# Can we formally prove that XOR operations 'cancel'?

Tags: boolean-algebra, cryptography

Suppose I have two sequences of binary bits m1 and m2, and an
accompanying 'key string' K of bits with all three the same length.

Then if I define c1 and c2 as:

```
c1 = (m1 XOR K)  
c2 = (m2 XOR K)
```

I find that

```
c1 XOR c2  =  m1 XOR m2
```

Informally, I have found by trial and error
that the XOR's with K are canceled out.

I would like to see this proven formally. Can anyone recommend
a text or a website that would serve as a reference ?
Or if this is simple to prove (I imagine it is for someone
more experienced than me!), a proof would be great.

(For context: I am taking a cryptography course and this
came up at the point where they covered why
one should never use a stream cipher key more than once.)

Thanks !

UPDATE: great answers.. at my level of knowledge i should have opted for the truth table approach suggested by @peterwhy

Comment: You can find proofs on this site that XOR is associative, commutative, and self-inverse. Use that to show $(m_1 \oplus K) \oplus (m_2 \oplus K) = (m_1 \oplus m_2) \oplus (K \oplus K) = m_1 \oplus M_2$.

Comment: A truth table for the corresponding bits of $m_1,m_2,K$ would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XOR is the usual addition in abelian group $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, so it is associative and commutative. Moreover, $$n+n\equiv 2n \equiv 0 \pmod 2$$ so both bits are inverse to themselves with respect to XOR. Putting this together we have
$$(m+k)+(n+k) \equiv m+(k+n)+k \equiv m+(n+k)+k\equiv (m+n)+(k+k) \equiv m+n \pmod 2.$$
Now, if we have strings of bits, for each positive integer $n$, bitwise XOR is given as addition in $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^n$ which is defined pointwise so the above calculation is true for each bit, and therefore for strings of bits.